# What is the name of the sorting algorithm where you find the lowest value, add it to result and remove it from original list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I really don't know if this kind of question is suitable in this website. I've been trying to understand the sorting algorithms nowadays and a new algorithm to sort a list of numbers has come to my mind and I wanted to implement it.

So here's the result:

```py
def sort(obj: list) -> list:
    result = []
    for _ in range(len(obj)):
        _biggest = 0
        for i in obj:
            _biggest = i if i > _biggest else _biggest
        _lowest = _biggest
        for i in obj:
            _lowest = i if _lowest > i else _lowest
        result.append(_lowest)
        obj.remove(_lowest)
    return result
```

This algorithm basically gets the biggest value in the given list first, then find the lowest value with the help of biggest value, adds the lowest value found to a new list named `result` and finally removes the lowest value from the original list. Loops this until the list is empty.

I googled all the fastest sorting algorithms and this one was faster than many of them. So I decided to find out whether the algorithm I've come up with was already a thing or not, but I couldn't find any algorithm that works like that.

I'm sure I'm not the only one found this way. What's the name of this algorithm? Is there a drawback of this algorithm that makes it not proper?

Comment: Maybe you've meant find **max** value first? Then it looks like *[selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is selection sort. Also, this could be improved by using the MAX_INT for biggest so you can eliminate the first loop to find the biggest value. That would take it from N×2N to N×N complexity.

Comment: Wow, I'm not the only one :D Thank you so much for the answer and the suggestion as well!